# Give the definition of S $\subseteq$ T for general sets S and T.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

The answer I can come up with is;

*S* is a subset of *T*, denoted by *S* $\subseteq$ *T*, or equivalently, T is a superset of S, denoted by *T* $\supseteq$ *S*.

Can someone correct me if I am wrong, or provide a better answer? Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning of the symbol $\subseteq$, or asking about the definition of the relation of being a subset? By the way, you probably meant to write $T\supseteq S$ on the right.

Comment: @Sumeet: the definition of $S\subseteq T$ is that $S$ is a subset of $T$. But then also $T\supseteq S$ with the meaning: $T$ is a superset of $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not really good (as far as I can guess), because $S\subseteq T$ is pronounced "$S$ [is a] subset [of] $T$", so you essentially define subset by saying that it means being a subset.

My guess is that the question is asking you give give the mathematical definition of being a subset, which I'll leave for you to locate in your notebook.

Answer (score 1):

We say that $S$ is a subset of $T$ if any element of $S$ is an element of $T$, and we say that $S$ is a *proper* subset of $T$ if $S$ is a subset of $T$ and $S\neq T$. Being a [proper] superset is the opposite relation.

$\subseteq$ is a symbol denoting the relation of inclusion (i.e. of being a subset). Nowadays it has (from what I've seen) nearly completely superseded $\subset$, having the advantage of being less ambiguous: some authors would use $\subset$ to denote *proper* inclusion (like we differentiate between $<$ and $\le$).

A modern, unambiguous convention is to write $\subsetneq$ to denote proper inclusion, and $\subseteq$ to denote any (possibly improper) inclusion. Both have symmetric counterparts, namely $\supsetneq,\supseteq$.